# rust: py03 how to get reference to struct member

Tags: rust, pyo3

How do I edit Header.a via Packet.Header.a?

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Header {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    a: u32,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    b: u32,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Header {
    #[new]
    fn new(a: u32, b: u32) -> Self {
        Header { a, b }
    }
}

#[pyclass]
/// Structure used to hold an ordered list of headers
pub struct Packet {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    pub h: Header,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Packet {
    #[new]
    fn new() -> Self {
        Packet {
            h: Header { a: 0, b: 0 },
        }
    }
}

#[pymodule]
fn pyo3test(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Header>()?;
    m.add_class::<Packet>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

After running "maturin develop", within python

```
from pyo3test import *
p = Packet()
print(p.h.a) # prints 0
h = p.h
h.a = 1
print(h.a) -> # prints 1
print(p.h.a) -> # still prints 0
p.h.a = 1
print(p.h.a) # still prints 0
```

This seems against python semantics. h is a reference to p.h. An update to h should have updated p.h.
How do I implement the get trait to return a reference to Packet.Header?

Comment: While this is not the exact same question, I think the answer hits the nail on the head.
The problem is that they have different memory models - Rust is ownership based, and Python is reference counted. This is one of those situations where the only possible solution is a compromise.
Technically it would be possible to model Python's ownership model (somehow) with `Arc<Mutex<...>>`, but I don't think this is currently in PyO3.

Comment: To show that this is in fact PyO3's intended behaviour, read [this chapter of their documentation](https://pyo3.rs/main/class.html#object-properties-using-pyo3get-set), which states *"For `get` the field type must implement both `IntoPy<PyObject>` and `Clone`."*.

Comment: Thank you. I am a newbie to Rust and this seems a clever solution for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not an expert on PyO3. I just somewhat have an understanding of how Rust and Python work. So take everything I say with a grain of salt.

The problem here is that Rust and Python have a very different memory model. While Rust is ownership based, Python is reference-counted. This creates some challenges in implementing classes that are usable in both languages.

Specifically for getters/setters, it seems that PyO3 [decided to `clone()`](https://pyo3.rs/main/class.html#object-properties-using-pyo3get-set) instead of reference counting:

> For `get` the field type must implement both `IntoPy<PyObject>` and `Clone`.

There are further incompatibilities: Python is not typesafe. That means that any item could be of any type, for example, you could write:
`p.h.a = "Test"`, although the definition `Header::a` in Rust is clearly a `u32`. This also "seems to be against python semantics".

---

That said, you could achieve something similar by using reference counters internally. You cannot, however (at the time of writing and from what I could tell) expose those reference counters to Python. (Meaning, you cannot use something like `Arc<Header>` and return this from a getter)

But you could make `Header` itself somewhat of a reference counter:

```
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
    Arc,
};

use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Header {
    a: Arc<AtomicU32>,
    b: Arc<AtomicU32>,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Header {
    #[new]
    fn new(a: u32, b: u32) -> Self {
        Header {
            a: Arc::new(AtomicU32::new(a)),
            b: Arc::new(AtomicU32::new(b)),
        }
    }

    #[getter]
    fn get_a(&self) -> PyResult<u32> {
        Ok(self.a.load(Ordering::Acquire))
    }

    #[setter]
    fn set_a(&mut self, value: u32) -> PyResult<()> {
        self.a.store(value, Ordering::Release);
        Ok(())
    }

    #[getter]
    fn get_b(&self) -> PyResult<u32> {
        Ok(self.b.load(Ordering::Acquire))
    }

    #[setter]
    fn set_b(&mut self, value: u32) -> PyResult<()> {
        self.b.store(value, Ordering::Release);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[pyclass]
/// Structure used to hold an ordered list of headers
pub struct Packet {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    pub h: Header,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Packet {
    #[new]
    fn new() -> Self {
        Packet {
            h: Header::new(0, 0),
        }
    }
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
#[pyo3(name = "rust_python_test")]
fn rust_python_test(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Header>()?;
    m.add_class::<Packet>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from rust_python_test import Packet

p = Packet()
print(p.h.a) # prints 0
h = p.h
h.a = 1
print(h.a) # prints 1
print(p.h.a) # prints 1
p.h.a = 1
print(p.h.a) # prints 1
```